# ionic v2 calling a function from caller page in provider

Tags: angularjs, ionic2

I have a case in which I want to call  a function (f1) in a provider and then from that function (f1) I want to call another function in the page.

this is the code for page1.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import {Utils} from '../../providers/utils';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-page1',
  templateUrl: 'page1.html'
})
export class Page1 {

  //storage: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public storage: Storage, public utils: Utils) {

   
    
  }

  test()
  {
    this.utils.testOut(this.ret);
  }
  ret()
  {
    console.log(this);
  }

}
```

and Utils.ts which is the provider is:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http , Headers} from '@angular/http';

/*
  Generated class for the HttpHelper provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class Utils {

  constructor(private http: Http, private applicationConstants: ApplicationConstants) {
    //console.log('Hello utils Provider');
    //this.http = http;

    
  }

  

  testOut(success:Function)
  {
      success();
  }

}
```

but when It enters again page1.ts, it prints in console.log "undefined" 
it means page1.ts is not available with all of its variables and functions.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

If you call a function in page1.ts from utils.ts, you should import page1.ts first.

Comment: I import, but the same thing